# File extension is change upper case to lower case in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading file in codeigniter using

```
$this->upload->do_upload('image')
```

but when file moves to particular path the file extension is changed (it's changed to lower case)

for example if I upload file "profile.JPG" it's changes to "profile.jpg"

Comment: I would of thought this is a benefit, you now know to expect all extensions to be in lowercase. If you're saving the file name in a database that's breaking when you retrieve it due to case sensitivity, just strtolower() all file names when inserting to DB

Comment: Yes Johnny that is the benefit of that but why codeigniter change it.? and strtolower() is good option thanks for that.

Comment: I'm not sure why, my best guess would be because some systems are case sensitive, so this normalizes all file extensions on uploads. Migrating your site to a case sensitive system from a non case sensitive system might prove to be troublesome otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change CI system library

default in CI upload library $file_ext_tolower = FALSE.

.system\libraries\upload.php

```
public $file_ext_tolower = TRUE;
```

Comment: Or you can change the config in the controller instead: `$config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;` and then `$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Answer (score 1):

do_upload does this

**$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'**

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

If you want to use same name / extension you send to save your file. You can use :

```
$upload_dir= $this->config->item("upload_dir");
$fileName =  $_POST['sku_code'].".".$extension;
$filePath = $upload_dir.$fileName;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image-file"]["tmp_name"],$filePath );
```

**Useful link :**

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html